# Find all OSX files with specific 'color' label

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, applescript

Is there any way in terminal to list all finder files with a specific color label? 
(i.e 'find all files with red label'

I know this is possible in spotlight. Looking for a way to incorporate this into applescript/terminal.

Answer (score 4):

in terminal you can use mdfind directly. It is the command line client for spotlight :)

e.g.

```
$ mdfind -onlyin . -literal 'kMDItemFSLabel > 0'  # labels have value 50
/cwd/labelled_file.jpg

$ mdfind -onlyin . -literal 'kMDItemFSLabel == 0'
/cwd/all.jpg
/cwd/other.jpg
/cwd/files.jpg
```

you can call that in a shell script too of course ;)

src for example: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31919/how-do-you-list-items-with-and-without-labels-from-the-terminal

Answer (score 1):

In Applescript The Applescript code to get files by label would be (note the use of an integer for defining colors):

```
set yellow to 3
tell application "Finder"
    files of folder "path:to:folder:" whose label index is yellow
end tell
```

And the codes are:

```
None   = 0
Red    = 2
Orange = 1
Yellow = 3
Green  = 6
Blue   = 4
Purple = 5
Gray   = 7
```

Comment: he wants the file in the terminal.

Comment: The question says "applescript/terminal." I take that to mean one or the other.

Comment: ok.. dont see it working for him :/ but you're right. didn't read till the end ;) sorry